# Concat in a Loop within XSL file?

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xslt

I have a distinct XML file which I am attempting to transform with an XSL file to support being imported by another application.  I am very new to XML transform and on a short timeline so forgive me if I haven't exhausted every last site that google returns on the most ideal way to do this.

The original XML (which is converted from JSON initially)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SecurityGroups>
    <Description>DEV-CUSTOMER-VPC-AD</Description>
    <Tags>
        <Value>DEV-CUSTOMER-VPC-AD</Value>
        <Key>Name</Key>
    </Tags>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>42424</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>42424</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>464</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>464</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>4500</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>4500</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>389</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>389</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>53</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>53</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>3389</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>3389</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>445</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>445</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>1813</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>1813</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>1900</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>1900</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>139</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>139</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>135</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>135</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>53</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>53</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>500</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>500</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>52997</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>57000</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>80</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>80</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>464</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>464</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>593</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>593</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>389</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>389</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>123</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>123</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>443</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>443</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>9389</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>9389</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>3268</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>3269</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>88</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>88</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>52997</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>57000</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>137</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>138</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>1812</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>1812</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>2869</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>2869</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>636</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>636</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>tcp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <IpPermissions>
        <FromPort>88</FromPort>
        <IpRanges>
            <CidrIp>10.0.0.0/8</CidrIp>
        </IpRanges>
        <ToPort>88</ToPort>
        <IpProtocol>udp</IpProtocol>
    </IpPermissions>
    <GroupName>DEV-CUSTOMER-VPC-AD</GroupName>
    <VpcId>vpc-a2a754c7</VpcId>
    <OwnerId>006895185235</OwnerId>
    <GroupId>sg-27c51342</GroupId>
</SecurityGroups>
```

I have the following XSL file so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/SecurityGroups">
  <SecurityGroups>
    <Description><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></Description>
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="GroupName" /></Name>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="following::FromPort">;</xsl:if>
  </SecurityGroups>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like the FromPort integers to appear comma seprated like the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Export type="PortList" date="January 25, 2017 19:03" version="9.6.3177">
    <PortLists>
        <PortList id="119">
            <TBUID></TBUID>
            <Name>Active Directory Domain Services</Name>
            <Description>Mainly for Active Directory Servers North of 2k8 to 2k12</Description>
            <Items>88,1812,137-138,123,445,500,1813,1900,52997 - 57000,53,389,464</Items>
            <Version></Version>
            <UserEdited>true</UserEdited>
        </PortList>
    </PortLists>
</Export>
```

If anyone out there recognizes some of this I am trying to parse an AWS Security Group for automated import into a TrendMicro DSM Firewall Rule.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather confusing, because the output you show does not seem to be the exact output you want.

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SecurityGroups">
    <SecurityGroups>
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
        </Description>
        <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupName" />
        </Name>
        <Items>
            <xsl:for-each select="IpPermissions">
                <xsl:value-of select="FromPort"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Items>
    </SecurityGroups>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecurityGroups>
   <Description>DEV-CUSTOMER-VPC-AD</Description>
   <Name>DEV-CUSTOMER-VPC-AD</Name>
   <Items>42424,464,4500,389,53,3389,445,1813,1900,139,135,53,500,52997,80,464,593,389,123,443,9389,3268,88,52997,137,1812,2869,636,88</Items>
</SecurityGroups>
```